# CLI-Interface getChar() timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am using VS Code 1.15.1 with Node.js version 6.11.4.

Having installed 'cli-interface', I wanted to use the getChar() function to ask a question for user input. The issue I am facing is that after I enter a character (and I do press ENTER), nothing gets registered and the code after the prompting never gets hit. Here's how the code looks.

```
var query = require('cli-interface');
let input;
while(input != 'q')
{
  input = query.getChar('Choose an option','abcdeq');
  switch(input){
  ...
  }
}
```

The output shown in the debugger console:

```
Please select an option
Choose one of (a/b/c/d/q)? 
a
timeout after 10000 ms
c
timeout after 10000 ms
q
not available
b
cancelled because Node.js is unresponsive
```

Comment: are you pressing [ENTER] after you type the char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code does not currently support CLI-Interface debugging, so using the Node.js command line will make it work. Simply run the js file using the Node cmd program like so:

```
node <file_name>.js
```